# Counting unique days with overlap and gaps in date ranges

Tags: r, date, dplyr

```
Group       Start            End             Days
A           5/12/2015        5/14/2015       3
A           5/12/2015        5/14/2015       3
B           1/1/2015         1/3/2015        3
B           1/1/2015         1/3/2015        3
H           1/8/2015         1/9/2015        2
H           1/8/2015         1/9/2015        2
H           1/13/2015        1/15/2015       3
H           1/7/2015         1/17/2015       3
H           1/12/2015        1/22/2015       7
```

I've attached a sample of my dataset above. I'm trying to count the number of unique days for each group in R. For some observations its quite simple i.e A and B. However there are some groups with varying overlap of days as well as gaps in the date ranges i.e H.

Is there anyway I can summarize the number of unique days (no overlap and accounting for the gaps) for each group in R? i.e A and B would return 3 days respectively, and H would return 11 days.

```
Group   Count
A       3
B       3
H       16
```

My best guess would be using the dplyr and summarize function, however I haven't been able to wrap my head around any solution.
Any help is appreciated! Thank you

Comment: nicely worded question. Could you elaborate on how case three should sum to 11

Comment: My apologies the correct count should have been 16 as mentioned below!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    group_by(Group,rn = row_number()) %>%
    do(data.frame(.,Date = seq(as.Date(.$Start,format = '%m/%d/%Y'),
                               as.Date(.$End,format = '%m/%d/%Y'),
                               '1 day'))) %>%
    group_by(Group) %>%
    summarise(numDays = n_distinct(Date))
```

The idea is to create a new column which contains a sequence of dates from Start to End, and then count the length of unique observations in each group.

This gives:

```
   Group numDays
  (fctr)   (int)
1      A       3
2      B       3
3      H      16
```

Comment: That worked! This has been bothering me for days until I decided to make an account on here. You guys are amazing!

Comment: You could also use `n_distinct` instead of the `length` & `unique` combo: `numDays = n_distinct(Date)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @ProcrastinatusMaximus! I've updated the answer to use n_distinct.

Comment: Thats really neat, I wasn't aware of `seq()` nor the `n_distinct()` that @ProcastinatusMaximus suggested.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to count the unique days by group, I would do (assuming your `Start` and `End` columns are in date-format):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[, .(dates = seq.Date(Start,End,'day')) , by = .(Group,1:nrow(mydf))
            ][, .(count = uniqueN(dates)), by = Group][]
```

which gives:

```
   Group count
1:     A     3
2:     B     3
3:     H    16
```

*Explanation*: For each row you create date sequences with the `Start` and `End` dates. After that you count the unique days with the `uniqueN` function. This is better than my old answer (see below) because this takes gaps into account.

This gives a higher number for the `H` group compared to your described desired output. However, if you look closely to your data, you will see that the correct number is `16`.

---

A similar solution with base R:

```
l <- mapply(seq.Date, mydf$Start, mydf$End, 1)
df2 <- data.frame(group = rep(mydf$Group,sapply(l,length)),
                  dates = unlist(l))
aggregate(dates ~ group, df2, function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

which gives a similar result:

```
  group dates
1     A     3
2     B     3
3     H    16
```

If you want the `dates` column in `df2` in date-format, use `as.Date(unlist(l), origin = '1970-01-01')` instead of `unlist(l)`.

---

Used data:

```
mydf <- structure(list(Group = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H"), 
                       Start = structure(c(16567, 16567, 16436, 16436, 16443, 16443, 16448, 16442, 16447), class = "Date"), 
                       End = structure(c(16569, 16569, 16438, 16438, 16444, 16444, 16450, 16452, 16457), class = "Date"), 
                       Days = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 7L)), 
                  .Names = c("Group", "Start", "End", "Days"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for thorough explanation! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @MichaelLuu I've also included a base R approach.